# Расссылка сообщений группы вк

Tags: python, python-3.x, вконтакте

Итак, у меня есть группа вк. Ей надо время от времени делать рассылку. Необходимо автоматизировать весь этот процесс через vk api. Я авторизировался как сообщество, с этим проблем не возникло. Затем возникла необходимость получить айди всех участников сообщества. Вот тут я и остановился, обычные методы не работали, ибо я был не пользователем, а группой. Как это можно решить?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import vk

token = ''
session = vk.Session(access_token = token)
vk = vk.API(session, scope = 'groups', v ='5.62')
followers = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id = 'bloodys_arts')
print(followers['items'])
```

Comment: _"обычные методы не работали"_, — какие? И как Вы их вызывали? Документация говорит, что [`groups.getMembers`](https://vk.com/dev/groups.getMembers) можно вызвать, используя токен сообщества.

Comment: Его я и использовал, возможно ошибка была в чем-то другом, свой код я дополнил в посте

Comment: Что значит "не работали"? Возникала ошибка или что?

Comment: @insolor Ошибка есть в оригинальном вопросе (это дубликат).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, проблема решена: все дело в том, что сообщество принадлежало не мне.